# Laravel 5 Auth Filter do not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just tried Laravel 5 after a time at 4.2.. 
The docs says it is possible to use `'before' => 'auth'` as always, but for me it does not work.

I have no idea whats wrong, I have read the docs, search on internet but seems not to find anything.
My code looks as:

```
$router->group(['before' => 'auth'], function($router)
{

     // 
     $router->get('admin', function()
     {
          return View::make('admin.index');
     });

     //
     $router->get('login', function()
     {
          return View::make('admin.login');
     });

});
```

Anyone can see what I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you have in `auth` filter? What url are you testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In laravel5 filters are removed. Instead you can use middleware classes which are more clean.

In [this](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-replacing-filters) blog you can read more about the middleware classes and that they're a replacement of filters.

If you want to do it with self written routes you can use this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{

     Route::get('admin', function()
     {
          return View::make('admin.index');
     });

     Route::->get('login', function()
     {
          return View::make('admin.login');
     });

});
```